# Not possible to set content-type to application/json using urllib2

Tags: python, json, post, urllib2

This little baby:

```
import urllib2
import simplejson as json

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders.append(('Content-Type', 'application/json'))
response = opener.open('http://localhost:8000',json.dumps({'a': 'b'}))
```

Produces the following request (as seen with ngrep):

```
sudo ngrep -q -d lo '^POST .* localhost:8000'

T 127.0.0.1:51668 -> 127.0.0.1:8000 [AP]
  POST / HTTP/1.1..Accept-Encoding: identity..Content-Length: 10..Host: localhost:8000..Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded..Connection: close..User-Agent:
   Python-urllib/2.7....{"a": "b"}
```

I do not want that `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I am explicitely saying that I want `('Content-Type', 'application/json')`

What's going on here?!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to set custom headers you should use a `Request` object:

```
import urllib2
import simplejson as json

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
req = urllib2.Request('http://localhost:8000', data=json.dumps({'a': 'b'}),
      headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
response = opener.open(req)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve my problem. The code is already implemented (legacy), and I just need to change the `Content-Type`. Why does `opener.addheaders.append` not work as expected?

Comment: The headers in `addheaders` are only added if no corresponding header has been added, but if you use a `data` argument the content type is already set implicitly to the default (x-www-form-urlencoded). In this case this takes precedence over the headers in `addheaders`.

Comment: This behaviour is a bit unexpected. Anyway, thanks to your suggestion I have been able to get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got hit by the same stuff and came up with this little gem:

```
import urllib2
import simplejson as json

class ChangeTypeProcessor(BaseHandler):
    def http_request(self, req):
        req.unredirected_hdrs["Content-type"] = "application/json"
        return req

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
self.opener.add_handler(ChangeTypeProcessor())
response = opener.open('http://localhost:8000',json.dumps({'a': 'b'}))
```

You just add a handler for HTTP requests that replaces the header that `OpenerDirector` previously added.

Answer (score 0):

Python version:`Python 2.7.15`
I found that in `urllib2.py:1145`:

```py
        for name, value in self.parent.addheaders:
            name = name.capitalize()
            if not request.has_header(name):
                request.add_unredirected_header(name, value)

...
    def has_header(self, header_name):
        return (header_name in self.headers or
                header_name in self.unredirected_hdrs)
```

Otherwise,`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` has been in unredirected_hdrs and it won't be overwrite

You can solve like

```py
import urllib.request
from http.cookiejar import CookieJar

import json

url = 'http://www.baidu.com'
req_dict = {'k': 'v'}

cj = CookieJar()
handler = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)

req_json = json.dumps(req_dict)
req_post = req_json.encode('utf-8')
headers = {}
#headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, data=req_post, headers=headers)

#urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
#res = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
# or
res = opener.open(req)

res = res.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the capitalization of the Header name. You should use `Content-type` and not `Content-Type`.