# Unexpected behavior between between using urllib2 Request vs build_opener with posted JSON (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

EDIT:

Found the solution.  Since the RBC endpoint is https, the handler class is required to have a https_request function as well, not just a http_request.

[Solution for http endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920211/not-possible-to-set-content-type-to-application-json-using-urllib2)

```py
class ChangeTypeProcessor(urllib2.BaseHandler):
    def http_request(self, req):
        req.unredirected_hdrs["Content-type"] = "application/json"
        req.unredirected_hdrs["User-Agent"] = "Python-urllib/2.7"
        return req

    def https_request(self, req):
        req.unredirected_hdrs["Content-type"] = "application/json"
        req.unredirected_hdrs["User-Agent"] = "Python-urllib/2.7"
        return req
```

---

I am encountering strange behavior difference when using the two different methods of posting JSON data using the urllib2 library in python.  Although I know requests exists, I am working with legacy software which makes it harder to make a switch.  The legacy software also uses the build_opener method of posting data.

The request object is able to successfully obtain JSON data/response back when trying to post JSON to RBC's job search.  However, the OpenerDirector isn't a to successfully gain a response when posting JSON to RBC's job bank.

The following is a tester that I am using to attempt to get the job data from RBC:

```py
import json
import urllib2
import urlparse

class ChangeTypeProcessor(urllib2.BaseHandler):
    def http_request(self, req):
        req.unredirected_hdrs["Content-type"] = "application/json"
        req.unredirected_hdrs["User-Agent"] = "Python-urllib/2.7"
        return req

data = '{"lang":"en_ca","deviceType":"desktop","country":"ca","ddoKey":"refineSearch","sortBy":"","subsearch":"","from":100,"all_fields":[],"pageName":"search-results","counts":true,"jobs":true,"keywords":"","global":true,"size":50,"sele
cted_fields":null,"sort":null}'
url = "https://jobs.rbc.com/widgets"
#url = "http://httpbin.org/post"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

response = urllib2.urlopen(request, data)

urlopener = urllib2.build_opener()
urlopener.add_handler(ChangeTypeProcessor())
print(response.read())

connection = urlopener.open(url, data)
print(connection.read())
```

The following is the error the OpenDirector produces when posting to the site:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jsonPost.py", line 23, in <module>
    connection = urlopener.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

The following is the posted data obtained with http://httpbin.org/post :

Response with request object:

```js
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\"lang\":\"en_ca\",\"deviceType\":\"desktop\",\"country\":\"ca\",\"ddoKey\":\"refineSearch\",\"sortBy\":\"\",\"subsearch\":\"\",\"from\":100,\"all_fields\":[],\"pageName\":\"search-results\",\"counts\":true,\"jobs\":true,\"keywords\":\"\",\"global\":true,\"size\":50,\"selected_fields\":null,\"sort\":null}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity",
    "Content-Length": "259",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "Python-urllib/2.7"
  },
  "json": {
    "all_fields": [],
    "country": "ca",
    "counts": true,
    "ddoKey": "refineSearch",
    "deviceType": "desktop",
    "from": 100,
    "global": true,
    "jobs": true,
    "keywords": "",
    "lang": "en_ca",
    "pageName": "search-results",
    "selected_fields": null,
    "size": 50,
    "sort": null,
    "sortBy": "",
    "subsearch": ""
  },
  "origin": "<hidden>",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Response with the OpenDirector:

```js
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\"lang\":\"en_ca\",\"deviceType\":\"desktop\",\"country\":\"ca\",\"ddoKey\":\"refineSearch\",\"sortBy\":\"\",\"subsearch\":\"\",\"from\":100,\"all_fields\":[],\"pageName\":\"search-results\",\"counts\":true,\"jobs\":true,\"keywords\":\"\",\"global\":true,\"size\":50,\"selected_fields\":null,\"sort\":null}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity",
    "Content-Length": "259",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "Python-urllib/2.7"
  },
  "json": {
    "all_fields": [],
    "country": "ca",
    "counts": true,
    "ddoKey": "refineSearch",
    "deviceType": "desktop",
    "from": 100,
    "global": true,
    "jobs": true,
    "keywords": "",
    "lang": "en_ca",
    "pageName": "search-results",
    "selected_fields": null,
    "size": 50,
    "sort": null,
    "sortBy": "",
    "subsearch": ""
  },
  "origin": "<hidden>",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Noticeably, the information given by httpbin shows that the data being posted is exactly the same but for some reason, OpenDirector is unable to obtain a proper response.

My desired solution is to make the OpenDirector successfully obtain a proper response without reimplementing the code base to using requests or the Request object.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the discrepancy?

Comment: I fail to see why it matters that your request to OpenDirector and httpbin are the same. The `500` implies the issue is on their end, which could effectively be a `400` if the issue is with your request data, but there's really no way of knowing since I don't see any API docs for this endpoint.

Comment: @Jack My earlier findings found that the OpenDirector changes the 'Content-Type' header to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' by default unless you added a handler.  This made me believe that there was a difference in how the data was sent since it was causing the JSON data not be transmitted properly.  However, thanks to your comment I was able to figure out why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.  Since the RBC endpoint is https, the handler class is required to have a https_request function as well, not just a http_request.

[Solution for http endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13920211/not-possible-to-set-content-type-to-application-json-using-urllib2)

```py
class ChangeTypeProcessor(urllib2.BaseHandler):
    def http_request(self, req):
        req.unredirected_hdrs["Content-type"] = "application/json"
        req.unredirected_hdrs["User-Agent"] = "Python-urllib/2.7"
        return req

    def https_request(self, req):
        req.unredirected_hdrs["Content-type"] = "application/json"
        req.unredirected_hdrs["User-Agent"] = "Python-urllib/2.7"
        return req
```